# IOrderedQueryable<T> and Take()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

What I need is to order IQueriable (the result of LINQ to SQL method) and return first *count* elements if *count* is defined. I use the following code:

```
IOrderedQueryable<MainLog> list = logs.OrderByDescending(item => item.Time);
if (count > 0) list = list.Take(count).OrderByDescending(item=>item.Time);
```

It works fine, but I don't like calling OrderByDescending twice. Can I make it any better without breaking the order and also without double-ordering?

Comment: have you tried simply to eliminate the last ordebydescending (it's redundant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no need for the second `OrderByDescending`. Simply remove it:

```
IQueryable<MainLog> list = logs.OrderByDescending(item => item.Time); 
if (count > 0)
    list = list.Take(count);
```